# java logical issue dealing with numbers

Tags: java

I'm having a real case of the monday's. I'm trying to traverse a table of results based on the entry I'm looking for. For instance, the page displays 15 results at a time, and can have n results. I can't get the logic down to traverse these pages. I want to do this:
If entry isn't 1-15 go to page 2, if not 16-30 go to page 3, etc. Until I get to the page that the entry is on.
Another example: entry I'm looking for is 64 out of 300 entries, so I need to get to page 5 to view the entry.

I was doing different things with multiples of 15, modulo, etc, and can't get it to work.

Any help with this would be appreciated, getting another cup of coffee...

Comment: why don't you post parts of the code that do paging and lookups

Comment: only static is the # of the entry I'm looking for and 15 results per page. Could be n number of pages.

Comment: in what, methods, dont matter. It's a logic question. I just can't figure out the math needed to compute what # page. I'm providing all the important variables to the math equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
int pageNumber = ((resultNumber - 1) / pageSize) + 1;
```

(Assuming a 1-based page number and result number.)

That will map results 1-15 to page number 1, 16-30 to page 2, 31-45 to page 3 etc.

Comment: I think this will do it, thank you, couldn't figure it out for the life of me lol! Let me test this out.

Comment: What about something a little more 'leet: `int pageNumber = --resultNumber / pageSize + 1;`. And, "yes"... I think it *is* readable

Comment: @Bohemian that would change your resultNumber as a side effect.  Definately not preferable.

Comment: @Bohemian: Exactly as Joeri says, changing it to have side-effects *isn't* preferrable, IMO.

Comment: Of course - I really meant as the body of a method, ie `return --resultNumber / pageSize + 1;`. Never mind

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    Start offset = (Number of page - 1) * Results Per Page
    End offset = (Number of page) * Results Per Page
    Offset on a page = (Number of item) mod Results per page (Substract 1 to have zero-based index)
    Page Number = (Number of item - 1) / Results Per Page + 1 ( Substract 1 to have zero-based index)
```